# Correct way to handle curl_exec($ch) in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a php script that does an HTTP post. So far it is working as expected but I am not handling all possible errors (e.g. timeouts, invalid http address).

The statement that does the call is:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false)
{
    return 'Error';
}
else 
{
    return $result;
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle possible errors or should I use something more complex?

Comment: That depends on if you need to take different actions or display messaging... Depends completely on the requirements of you application.

Comment: You can get the error information via `curl_error()` how you decide to handle different errors is up to you.

Comment: I just need to know if there was an error or not. I am not interested in the error itself. Can you give some information in this sense? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should look at curl_error**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php